# ArrayIntList(java)

Tags: java

> Write a method isPairwiseSorted that returns whether or not a list of integers is pairwise sorted (true if it is, false otherwise). A list is considered pairwise sorted if each successive pair of numbers is in sorted (non-decreasing) order.

I wrote the following method but it always return true. Need some help here please.

```
public boolean isPairwiseSorted() {
    boolean isFalse=false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i+=2){
        if( elementData[i] < elementData[i+1] || size == 0 || size == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return isFalse;
}
```

Comment: this method always return true. It never return false.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (size == 0 || size == 1)
   return true;

for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i += 2)
{
   if (elementData[i] > elementData[i+1])
      return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: I guess it should be `i < size - 1` in case `i = size - 1` and trying to access to `element[i+1]` which will be `element[size]`

Comment: Thanks: good point.......